# Custom functions for SAVE and CANCEL on Leaflet.draw edit control

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-draw

I have added an edit control on my map which is working fine (On the Frontend);

```
var editControls = new L.Control.Draw({
      draw: false,
      edit: {
        featureGroup: this.updateGeomLyr
      }
    }).addTo(this.map);
```

[image]

Now, when I save or cancel my changes, the event "draw:editstop" is called

```
this.map.on("draw:editstop", e => {
      this.updateGeomLyr.clearLayers();
      this.overlapLyr.clearLayers();

      //if saved;

      //if cancelled,
    });
```

But I want separate backend functions to be called on SAVE ad CANCEL. I couldn't find any attribute in the event "e" which shows if save is called or cancel.

Answer (score 2):

`Leaflet.draw` plugin doesn't fire any event when editing is canceled. The only way to achieve this is to hack plugin by extending it. Since this requires taking part of the original code of plugin, tha downside of this is that it might now work with future versions of plugin.

`getActions` method of `L.EditToolbar` among other things sets callbacks for click events on edit toolbar buttons `Save` and `Cancel`. Callback for cancel (the second action) is now `this.disable`. This is replaced with new method `_cancel`, where first original action is called and then new `draw:editcancel` event fired.

```
L.EditToolbar.include({
  getActions: function (handler) {
    var actions = [
      {
        title: L.drawLocal.edit.toolbar.actions.save.title,
        text: L.drawLocal.edit.toolbar.actions.save.text,
        callback: this._save,
        context: this
      },
      {
        title: L.drawLocal.edit.toolbar.actions.cancel.title,
        text: L.drawLocal.edit.toolbar.actions.cancel.text,
//        callback: this.disable,  // --- original
        callback: this._cancel,    // --- changed
        context: this
      }
    ];

    if (handler.removeAllLayers) {
      actions.push({
        title: L.drawLocal.edit.toolbar.actions.clearAll.title,
        text: L.drawLocal.edit.toolbar.actions.clearAll.text,
        callback: this._clearAllLayers,
        context: this
      });
    }

    return actions;
  },

// --- new -----------------
  _cancel: function() {
    this.disable();
    this._map.fire('draw:editcancel');
  }  
});

function processCancel(e) {
  console.log('draw canceled');
}

map.on('draw:editcancel', processCancel);
```

Plugin extension has to be put at the very beginning of code.

Comment: Is this still true?: "Leaflet.draw plugin doesn't fire any event when editing is canceled" Because I attached a listener to "draw:editstop" with a `console.log()` statement inside and it still logs even when I hit the "cancel" button instead of the "save" button. Or have I misunderstood?