# Checking if a specific leaflet.draw control is enabled?

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-draw

Where exactly are the leaflet controls stored that are added to the map?
So at anytime in the app, I can check something like

```
if(controls.polyline.enabled==true)
```

My guess is its somewhere in the `map.layers`. But theres a lot of layers there. Any way to identify which one is our control layer? and then the attribute which checks if it is currently enabled or disabled.

Comment: You are posting new question without any feedback on an answer to your previous question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/331607/custom-functions-for-save-and-cancel-on-leaflet-draw-edit-control. Don't expect answers if you even don't make the effort to comment.

Answer (score 1):

Leaflet has no central repository/catalog of controls, neither has each control some default enabled/disabled property.

The closest you can get in `Leaflet.draw` plugin to check presence of individual draw elements in draw toolbar is to iterate through internal `drawControl._toolbars.draw._modes` object. This will list all active draw elements.

If `drawControl` is draw control created with `new L.Control.Draw(...`, then active draw elements can be listed with:

```
for (var drawMode in drawControl._toolbars.draw._modes) {
  if (drawControl._toolbars.draw._modes.hasOwnProperty(drawMode)) {
     console.log(drawMode);
  }
}
```